# Why does Selenium throw a "StaleElementReference" exception when I'm making a new lookup each time?

Tags: python, selenium

Testing a web-app in which I need to run a certain code on each page, so, while the next button is NOT disabled, I execute. When all pages are reviewed, the next button will get disabled, so the loop stops.

Found lots of questions on the topic, but most of them are storing the element in a variable in which case it makes total sense. In my case, `driver.find_element_by_class_name("nextPage")` is not stored in a variable, so shouldn't the element be located (again and again) at each iteration, getting a fresh element each time?

Now... I have managed to except the error and continue my test as you can see below, but I still don't get why is the exception executed, and it's totally random.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

i = 1

while True:

try:
    while driver.find_element_by_class_name("nextPage").is_enabled():

        print('page' + str(i))
        i += 1
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("nextPage").click()

except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print('An exception to a weird error, continuing loop...')
    continue

break
```

The Exception message is this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Well document.readyState just let you know that if the page is completely loaded or not. So it do not stop you from getting stale element as it cannot detect any ajax, or other such scripts in action.

Stale happens when an element was present and then the dom again was modified/loaded.

To get past this error, I have modified method something like this(in C#) :-

```
public static void StaleEnterTextExceptionHandler(this IWebDriver driver, By element, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.EnterText(element, value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.GetBaseException().Equals(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException)))
            {
                StaleEnterTextExceptionHandler(driver, element, value);
            }
            else
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

So it ensured that I will not get that error again. You can make it for click as well. Or just Wrap the selenium Click() with a new click method with stale handling functionality.

Hope it helps! let me know if there is anything else on this.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is the page is not completely loaded when the DOM is been searched causing the random failures.

Can you please add a wait for page to refresh. A sample code will be :-

```
wait.until(lambda d: d.execute_script("return document.readyState")=='complete')
```

I am not an regular python coder. So you may have to troubleshhot the code a bit too. The algorithm is to wait till the page is not ready or loaded. This is identified via the javascript code :: "return document.readyState")=='complete' ::

just add the above code after i+=1

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I have tried with Selenium's implicit waits and had the same issue. Now I'm thinking, if this was the case, shouldn't the error message be "Element not found", or whatever is the equivalent, rather than element stalled?

Comment: Implicit wait is failing because the element is no longer attached to DOM. So implicit wait wont work. you have to add explicit wait here. so when the implicit wait worked, the element was present, but then when other operation was performed, the element was detached.. most of the times because the page was still loading.